# Proving a point is a saddle point

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to prove a point is a saddle point, and the only information I have about it is that the value of the function is $0$ at this point and the determinant of the hessian is negative at the point. All the proofs I have found online and on this site use the eigenvalues of the hessian, however I have never learnt this. So far, I have wrote the second degree taylor expansion but am stuck from here. Any help is expected.

The question: “If $f: \mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a $C^3$ function such that $f(0,0)=0$ and $det(H(0,0))<0$. Prove that $(0,0)$ is a saddle point.

Comment: Would you like to provide the problem on which you are asking this question?

Comment: Ya, I’ll add it

Comment: I'm pretty sure we need to add the criterion that $(0, 0)$ is critical for $f$, that is $df(0, 0) = 0$ (or $\nabla f(0, 0) = 0$ if you like).  What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to prove is false:

$$
f(x, y)= x^2 - y^2 + 52x
$$
is a counterexample to the problem as stated; you really DO need for $(0,0)$ to be a critical point as well, as Robert Lewis stated.

Once you know that, it might help you to remember that the determinant of a $2 \times 2$ matrix is the product of its (two) eigenvalues.